# Disable Network Configuration in Auto install user-data

Tags: user-data

I am trying install Ubuntu using autoinstall.
Though I have not configured network in user-data file automatically dhcp IP gets assigned to the NIC.
How can we disable it in autoinstall of Ubuntu 22.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, the installer environment has its network configured by cloud-init using a [very generic netplan](https://git.launchpad.net/livecd-rootfs/tree/live-build/ubuntu-server/includes.chroot.ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg?id=90067f99e22ff4302c641048e2a708f0e74359a1#n21) configuration that uses DHCP on all physical interfaces.

Later, the installer (*subiquity*) will [apply the network configuration](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/fa351ed7bcab381cd2edcb595cace047be3a6a25/subiquitycore/controllers/network.py#L328) provided by the autoinstall file.

Therefore, you must use cloud-init to [disable networking](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config.html#disabling-network-configuration) for the initial installer environment **and** disable networking within the autoinstall file.

For the initial installer environment, I was able to disable networking using the kernel command line argument `network-config=disabled`.  The complete boot argument when using a  `nocloud` data source was

```
linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall network-config=disabled "ds=nocloud"
```

For the autoinstall file, it is enough to simply omit the `network` section.  Another option is to explicitly configure an empty network configuration like this.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  network:
    version: 2
    ethernets: {}
```

**notes**

- I tested using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`).